# Garbage collector for young generation

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Have sort question - is it true that all GC in JDK 7 (other than G1) always use stop-the-world for young generation collection?

thanks

Comment: Specifically to your "(other than G1)" note above: G1's young generation collections are just as stop-the-world and monolithic as all the other HotSpot collectors in the Oracle and OoenJDK JVMs. There are no non-stop-the-world young generation collectors in those JVMs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For OpenJDK, JRockit, IBM JVM, and Sun/Oracle JDK, the young collection is always stop the world for every available collector.

The only JVM I know of which does not have a stop the world collector is  Azul's Zing. (Not free)

While OpenJDK/Hotspot has CMS this is mostly concurrent.  There is still stop the world portions and in some cases CMS will fall back to a Full GC which is stop-the-world.

AFAIK, It is hard to find real world examples where G1 is faster in terms of pause time than CMS, however it is improving all the time.

[Do your GC logs speak to you](https://plus.google.com/102874451454074733659/posts/SKAqZHLwFyT)

Comment: To be specific, AFAIK, Zing is currently the only non-stop-the-world young generation collector in existence in a shipping JVM. For all other JVMs (Oracle, OpenJDK, J9, jRockit, ...) and for all their collectors, young generation collection is a monolithic stop-the-world event. And this doesn't appear to be changing any time soon.

Answer (score 5):

All (almost) Java garbage collectors has some sort of a Stop-the-world phase where all the Java threads  (not native threads) are suspended waiting for exclusive system operations to complete. This state is sometimes referred to as a safepoint.

The modern garbage collectors are concurrently running together with the applications threads, which means that the garbage collector perform its work at the same time as the application threads are running. During the garbage collector process there are phases where exclusive access memory is needed, in that phase the application Java threads goes into the safepoint state.

One alternative to get rid of the stop-the-world garbage collections is to go for the Zing JVM with the C4 collector from Azul systems. The implementation has a low pause approach with no stop-the-world collections at all. Instead it is using a concurrent compacting approach with no stop-the-world phase.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>No it is not true.</strike>  Java 7 also supports the older Concurrent Mark Sweep (CMS) collector.  CMS is a low pause collector, just like G1.

**UPDATE**

Apparently CMS is only for the tenured generation ... according to the blog posting that you found at http://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/our_collectors

So that means that your proposition is in fact true.

---

One could argue that all of the low-pause collectors:
  - need to stop the mutator threads to do some phases of their work, and 
  - may fall back to a Full GC using the mark/sweep collector when they can't keep up.

However, there is a qualitive difference between "mostly concurrent" collectors like G1 and CMS, and other collectors that suspend non-GC threads for the entire duration of the collection process.  That is what is normally meant by a "stop the world" strategy.

Comment: As I know CMS is used only for old and permanent generations...?

Comment: Where did you get that "information"?  I suggest you read this - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#cms

Comment: how about this: https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/our_collectors - is it too old?

Comment: The "mostly concurrent" part of CMS refers to non-compacting oldgen-only collection. ParNew (CMS's young gen collector) is an entirely stop-the-world collector, nothing concurrent about it.

Comment: G1 is not (and does not pretend to be) a mostly concurrent collector, even for oldgen. It does use a mostly concurrent marker, but it's incremental evacuations are entirely stop-the-world.

Comment: CMS is not only for old generation, but its young collection is just as STW as the other Hotspot GC algorithms. It uses multiple threads, like the Throughput collector and contrary to the Serial one.